# Event fees not showing on info page or registration page

Tags: civievent

Have set up an event with fees and pay later option (no payment processor installed yet)

The fee list does not show on the event info page,

And when following the register now link no fee option is given there either...

But if you complete the registration and billing contact details, you get an error message...

Please correct the following errors in the form fields below:
Select at least one option from Event Fee(s).

Running D7, and Civi 5.13.4

Checked on dmaster- can't replicate

Checked on another site running 5.13.4 and got the same error

Anyone else seen this?

Are there permissions I've not checked?

Comment: maybe add screenshots of your contrib screen in the event config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an issue with the CiviCalendar extension https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicalendar/330. Disabled the extension and it works. New update to CiviCalendar 3.30 fixes the issue.